# libusb 1.0 installation, for XP, for noob

Tags: python, libusb

I seem to be a fairly reasonable programmer once the configuration is set up, but am a noob at yak shaving, especially when there is a confusing choice of different yaks.

I am enjoying learning Python. It was the obvious choice with its abundance of libraries, native execution on both windows (for the moment) and linux (later, but not right now), and regular syntax. Up to now, everything I've wanted to add on has either just installed from a binary, or just been a simple file copy to the lib folder; pyaudio, numpy, videocapture, etc etc.

I am now tackling USB. I have bought a UM245R usb module and want to bit-bang it. I quickly learnt from PyUSB errors that I needed a backend. After a bit of reading, it appeared that as I have no legacy code, libusb1.0 was the appropriate choice. Is this correct?

Now my problems start. I am thoroughly confused about how to get it onto my PC. I have no tools or experience to build it from source, and cannot find anything that claims to be a self-installing .exe. I have seen a number of seperate installers mentioned, but cannot find any concensus on which uses what or is the correct way to go. I think I've been through all the replies here tagging libusb, without finding the specifics.

Would somebody who's done this for windows (XP SP3) take me by the hand and tell me what to use to install it please, for Python 2.6.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the pyUSB [tutorial](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html); "platform neutrality; ... PyUSB comes with builtin backends for libusb 0.1, libusb 1.0 and OpenUSB". So pyUSB doesn't really care what you use. But libusb 1 seems to be the safe choice.

Look at the [windows backend](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend) section of the libusb wiki. You'll find prebuilt windows binaries (zadig.exe, under "Driver Installation") for libusb 1.0 there.
There are [known restrictions](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend#KnownRestrictions) to the underlying Microsoft driver that might impact its usability; e.g. you cannot reset USB devices nor change the device configuration.